# location.href doesn't work with button

Tags: jquery, function, button, href

I want to assign the function below with a button, but by some reason the 'location.href' part in the function doen't work. If I change from a button to a div it works, so the problem seems to be with the button.

How come it doesn't work and is there a way of solving it (I really want to use a button)?

```
<button id="back">Cancel</button> // Doesn't work
<div id="back">Cancel</div> // Works

    $('#back').click(function(){
        var imageId = $('#id').attr('href');
        var id = imageId.split('/');
        location.href = '/blog/' + id[3];
    });
```

Comment: do you have an element with "id" as the Id in your DOM ?

Comment: If he hadn't then the `console.log(...)` wouldn't work either, would it? There's no reason this wouldn't work; unless you have *both* those elements (sharing an `id`) in the document at the same time. Can you [repro on JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not the button, your problem is the fact that when you bind a click to an element with a default behavior, like a `link` or `button`, the browser executes the script but first starts following the default behavior.

**You either use** `return false;` to prevent the default behavior from triggering, and also prevent other actions associated with the element to bubble up:

See this working [Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/eCB6N/)!

```
$('#back').click(function(){
    return false;  // prevent the regular click action for the element
    alert('bubu'); // this will not run
});
```

**or you use** `.preventDefault();` to only prevent the default behavior but perform other actions associated with the element:

See this working [Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/754zk/)!

```
$('#back').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault(); // prevent the regular click action for the element
    alert('bubu'); // this will run
});
```

There's a good article on the subject [here](http://css-tricks.com/return-false-and-prevent-default/)!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I managed to solve it myself. The thing is that you apparently need to add 'preventDefault();' if you're using a button to get 'location.href' to work.

My modified and now working code is:

```
    $('#back').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var imageId = $('#id').attr('href');
        var id = imageId.split('/');
        location.href = '/blog/' + id[3];
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like its an ID instead of class issue? I tried this example with ID and it didn't work, but switched to class and it was fine.

http://jsfiddle.net/rexzc/

Comment: Thanks, I actually got it to work even with an id. However, the 'location.href' part doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

A button will attempt to submit the form or document if clicked, you can use the type='button' attribute to prevent that.